# Connect RCassandra to Datastax with secure bundle zip file

Tags: r, cassandra, datastax, datastax-astra

I want to connect a code in R with datastax cassandra, I have found the package RCassandra and in several examples it shows how to connect to cassandra, but I need an example which adds a "secure-bundle.zip" which is required to connect to Datastax.

So far I got this:

```
install.packages("RCassandra")
 
library("RCassandra")
 
RC.connect(host="c58d5d9e-015a-4255-8f6c-05784a7c59ba-us-east1.db.astra.datastax.com",port=31808) -> con
 
RC.login(con, username = "user", password = "pwd")
```

But I need to add to this snippet a line for my "secure-bundle.zip". Is there a way to do that?
Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible to do with that package. The primary reason is that it's very old, and uses the obsolete Thrift protocol that isn't available for DataStax Astra.

P.S. more details in [the answer for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811330/cassandra-database-is-not-connecting-with-r-via-rcassandra/53970313#53970313) answered some time ago